# docker build fail, not resolving alias using directives

Tags: c#, .net, docker, sdk

I’m building a docker file based on:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-preview AS build
, when running:

```
RUN dotnet build "TSAS.Sim.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

in Linux image, it says:

```
#0 3.705 /src/TSAS.Models/GlobalUsings.cs(15,28): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/src/TSAS.Models/TSAS.Models.csproj]
#0 3.705 /src/TSAS.Models/GlobalUsings.cs(15,28): error CS1002: ; expected [/src/TSAS.Models/TSAS.Models.csproj]
```

where in line 15 of my GlobalUsings.cs is actually some alias using directives like:

```
global using Pos = (byte Bay, byte Row, byte Tier);
```

The directives are all good in Visual Studio itself and Windows, but in the docker image, it can’t be built correctly. And in my project it’s already been marked with:

```
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
        <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
        <AssemblyName>TSAS.Models</AssemblyName>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I switched to
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime:8.0.0-preview.4
and
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:8.0.100-preview.4
then the problem solved.